# How to access "project" folder in website (VS API)?

Tags: c#, plugins, visual-studio-2013, vs-web-site-project, visual-studio-sdk

I'm writing a Visual Studio editor plugin. This plugin's functionality includes modifying the project's folder and file structure. I also need access to physical folder where the project is being held. Currently I'm getting the project folder in the following way:

```
EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));
var projectItem = dte.Solution.FindProjectItem(pszMkDocument);
var project = projectItem.ContainingProject;
```

Then I may query `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(project.FileNames[0])` and get required path.

But how can I do so in case of website project in Visual Studio? Websites does not have project file as such, and the previous method returns a `http://` path instead of local path.

Answer (score 0):

The EnvDTE.Project.Properties collection contains a property named "FullPath" whose Value returns the physical folder for web site projects.

Answer (score -1):

you can use server.mappath

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Example.xml");
```

Comment: "I'm writing a Visual Studio editor plugin." I have no HttpContext there.

Comment: if any confusion. Ask me question.